# Rails SQL QUERY Like

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I've some problem with an SQL Query

I've users which have skills

```
  def skills=(value)
    super(value.reject(&:blank?).join("|")) if !value.nil?
   end

  def skills
   super.present? ? super.split("|") : []
  end
```

Here is my problem. When I query on this field with "like", word order matter. How can I avoid that ?

```
User.where("skills LIKE '%car%driving_license%'")
```

Each user with skills which at least contain car and driving_license

```
User.where("skills LIKE '%driving_license%car%'")
```

Each user with skills which at least contain car and driving_license  but in a different order

I want to be able to avoid this order problem. Any help ?

Comment: One option would be to split the `skills` string in your Ruby code, and then check each skill against a list of accepted skills, e.g. `WHERE skill1 IN ('driving_license', 'car') AND skill2 IN ('driving_license', 'car') AND ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sort the skills you can know the order and assemble a like query that will match both of them.  You can create a migration to sort the existing skills.

```
def skills=(value)
  super(value.reject(&:blank?).sort.join("|")) if value
end
```

`rails g migration sortUserSkills`

```
User.where.not(skills: nil).each do u
  u.skills = u.skills
  u.save
end
```

Comment: This is a good idea, I'll try it and come back if it's work! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

LIKE + OR queries are tough if my memory serves me.  You can try ARel, but I think you lose LIKE.

2 things I can think of:

1. Do the queries separately and combine results.
2. Use something like this which may not work:

   `conditions = ['%driving_license%car%', '%car%driving_license%']
    User.where("skills LIKE ?", conditions)`